# I'm trying to fix this hover effect.. HTML | CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix this hover effect where an orange layer covers the sign-up button, but instead, it covers the whole navbar. I'm not sure how to fix it. Some help would be appreciated, please & thanks.

Here is the HTML:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 555;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8d02;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#trade {
  background-color: #0045f2;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #833ab4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff871e;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar__btn:hover {
  color: #fff
}

.navbar__btn:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 135, 70);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Navbar Section -->
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">Pigeon<small id="trade">TRADE</small></a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Stackoverflow says i need to add more text in order to post so don't mind this, it's just filler text

Comment: It can be helpful if you can reproduce the problem in codepen: https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0110, also your question need more details.

Comment: if you give to `.navbar__btn` a `position:relative` the absolute pseudo will use it as  reference and will cover only that button, not the first positionned parent it finds higher in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've given the hover affect to a wrong class. Your sign up button has a class called "button" and it doesn't have a hover affect. You've given the hover affects to navbar__btn and navbar__links classes. If you fix this I believe you'll be fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

You were making the effect take `100%` of the `width` which wasn't right and as mentioned the class with the `:hover` effect was the wrong class

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 555;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8d02;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#trade {
  background-color: #0045f2;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
  bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 125px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #833ab4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff871e;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

/*Changed the class and removed the portion of the code which made it take 100% of the width*/
.button:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 135, 70);
  background: rgb(255, 135, 70);
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 135, 70);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 60vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }
  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }
  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }
  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }
  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }
  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Navbar Section -->
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar__container">
    <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">Pigeon<small id="trade">TRADE</small></a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```